# Converting Apache rewrite rules to IIS

Tags: iis

I have these rules setup in Apache and similar ones in NGINX. Now I want to setup in IIS. I haven’t got my head around IIS yet. Does anyone have links to some good resources to help me understand IIS rewrite rules to convert the Apache rules below? I already have ARR and rewrite rule modules installed in IIS.

Thanks

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ProxyPreserveHost On  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$                       
    RewriteRule / http://127.0.0.1:3000/?portgw=8080&alias=%1&theme=%1 [P]   
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/  
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/  
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost *:8080>  
    RequestHeader set Host "127.0.0.1:8010"  
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:8010/  
    ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:8010/  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Search engines should lead you to tons of articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules on Microsoft Docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL Rewrite Module in IIS 7 and above provides an import feature that greatly simplifies the process of converting Apache mod_rewrite rules to IIS URL rewrite rules.

More information about importing apache mod_rewrite rules to iis you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules.

Comment: That helps for the rewrite rules/conditions thanks. Now I just have to understand how to set the proxypass rules.

Comment: Thanks I think this has all helped. Seems to be working. Thanks